# java таблицы Пифагора

Tags: java

Подскажите кто в курсе как сделать вывод на экран таблицы Пифагора, от 2 до 9 включительно через один цикл на java?

Comment: Можно и вообще без циклов:

    System.out.println("2 * 2 = 4");
    System.out.println("2 * 3 = 6");
    System.out.println("2 * 4 = 8");

и т. д.

Сам текст программы можно сгенерировать другой программой, с циклами :-)

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, можно поступить так:
запускаешь цикл на 64 шага - по каждому значению счетчика цикла можно однозначно восстановить какие цифры перемножаются - вычислять это и сразу выводить. 
Значение числа можно определять так: разделить на 8 целую счетчика цикла от деления на 8 - так получится одно число. Другое число = (счетчик - 8*первое число)

Как только счетчика цикла становится кратен 8-ми (т.к. требуется вывести табличку с 2 до 9-ти => в ней 8 столбцов), то выводить значение и переходить на следующую строчку.

Comment: спс, попробуем

Comment: Просто первое, что пришло в голову...   будет что непонятное - спрашивайте)

Answer (score 2):

Странные задачи ныече в ВУЗах пошли.

Самое первое, что приходит в голову это обход по спирали, ну или в данном случае - строками.

Берете цикл не строки и столбцы, и их общее число, и делением выделяете столбцы и строки.
Самое мутное - сделать красивый вывод.

```
for (int j = 22; j < 99; j++)
{
  int Y = j/10;
  int X = j%10; // остаток от деления

  if (X == 0) System.out.println();
  if (X < 2 || X>9) continue;

  System.out.print(x + "\t");  
}
```

Общая идея выше. Ввиду отсутствия компилятора - тестирование и отладку оставляю вам.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5ZUMN/ ?

Comment: Пардон, не та переменная щас поправим.

Но в целом, думаю, вопрошающий до ума доведет дальше сам.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;
while(i++<100)
  System.out.print((i%10>0?i%10:10)*(i%10>0?(i/10+1):i/10)+(i%10!=0?"\t":"\n"));
```